# $f(n)=\Theta(f(n/2))$. Prove or disprove.

Tags: functions, asymptotics

I am trying to prove that the statement $f(n)=\Theta(f(n/2))$ is true. This is what I have so far. I am not sure it is correct.

Assume $f(n)=\Theta(f(\frac{n}{2}))$. Then $f(n)=O(f(\frac{n}{2}))$ and $f(n)=\Omega(f(\frac{n}{2}))$.

$f(n)=\Theta(f(\frac{n}{2}))$ means that there is a constant $c$ for which $f(n)\le c \cdot f(\frac{n}{2})$.
$f(n)=\Omega(f(\frac{n}{2}))$ means that there is a constant $c'$ for which $f(n) \ge c' \cdot f(\frac{n}{2})$.

Is this enough for the proof?

Comment: Maybe take a look at the Mathjax tutorial. It's a bit hard to read in this form.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The "proof" seems to be saying, in effect, 
"Assume $f(n) = \Theta(f(n/2))$. Then it follows that $f(n) = \Theta(f(n/2))$."

Try $f(n) = e^n$. Is the theorem true in that case?

Comment: I can see what you are saying. I tried it with the function f=(2^n) and I could see that very quickly the inequality 2^n<=c*2^(n/2) becomes false. I still don't understand how to write it as a formal proof though.

Comment: $2^n$ is a very good example. You can prove that no matter what value of $C$ you choose, there is a value of $n$ such that $2^n > C\cdot 2^{n/2}$.  If you simplify that inequality, it turns out all you need to show is that there is no limit on how large $2^{n/2}$ can be. This will show that $2^n \ne \Theta(2^{n/2})$.